# How to adjust the application select option menu?

Tags: lxde, menu

Environment:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
dpkg -s lxde
Maintainer: Debian LXDE Maintainers <pkg-lxde-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Source: lxde-metapackages
Version: 11
```

Right click mouse on a txt file:

[image]

How can I replace the *Libreoffice Calc* with *Mousepad*, or say, remove *Libreoffice Calc* and put *Mousepad* at the second just below *Open* in the menu?

```
file -i  test.txt
test.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

I fix the `mimeinfo.cache` on `text/plain`:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
text/plain=mousepad.desktop;vim.desktop;
```

Click on `test.txt`, the `Libreoffice-Calc` is still at the top of menu.
[image]

Maybe the OS treats `txt` as `csv` file.

```
text/plain=mousepad.desktop;vim.desktop;
text/rtf=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
text/spreadsheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
text/tab-separated-values=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
```

Comment: See edit. Also, is that a real csv or OS thinks so ?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to MIME type association. There maybe a graphical way like I have in KDE, check your LXDE settings first/click `Open with` and you may find an option to change this. Here is the generic texual way which should work under any DE/WM.
Edit `/usr/share/application/mimeinfo.cache`

```
text/plain=libreoffice-calc.desktop;gvim.desktop;libreoffice-writer.desktop;mousepad.desktop;vim.desktop;
```

(Something like this)
to

```
text/plain=mousepad.desktop;gvim.desktop;libreoffice-writer.desktop;vim.desktop;
```

(Remove LO Calc desktop file name from the list and cut Mousepad desktop file name and put it in the beginning)

This settings may be overridden by `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` and `/usr/local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`. So if the first method doesn't work, delete the `text/plain` line from these two files or paste the same valuse from first file to `text/plain` of these files.

**Edit:**
If the file is CSV, then you should apply the change to `application/csv` line.